# I run the following Dlookup expr to return prices from another query

Tags: date, ms-access, return, expression, dlookup

`Expr1: DLookUp("[price]","[query1]","[converted]<=" & [converted] & " And [item]='" & [item] & "'")` when converted is a date mm/dd/yyyy converted with CDbl(because i thought that I was wrong writing Expr with date criteria)
But again it return wrong

```
       item     date          converted        price
1   aa  21/10/2022    CDbl([date])  5
2   aa  23/10/2022              7
3   ab  18/10/2022              4
4   ac  21/10/2022              8
5   ab  21/10/2022              9
6   aa  30/10/2022              9
```

```
item    date           convertet    price
aa  26/10/2022  CDbl([date])    7   What I expect
aa  26/10/2022              9   What it return
**it return price from row 6 instead of row 2**
```

Comment: Why do you expect row 2? What are the inputs?

Comment: because the date on row 2 is <= then 26.10.2022

Comment: The date on row 2 is also less than 26.10.2002 and also item aa. So why would you expect row 2?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CDbl. Use the proper syntax for selecting a date and the original true date value:

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[price]","[query1]","[DateField] <= #" & Format([TrueDateValueField], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [item]='" & [item] & "'")
```

Comment: I think the wrong return comes because there are gaps between the dates in query 1

Comment: No. `DLookup` will just find "a" price at some date earlier then the specified. That will be 1 or 2.